# How to pass argument to karate.call

Tags: karate

I am passing argument to `karate.call` as following:

```
    ...getting object by name
    * def id = response.content[0].id
    And eval if (size(response.content) == 1) { karate.call('delete/delete-object.feature', id); }
```

However, I am getting: `unexpected feature call arg type: class java.lang.String`. Should I somehow cast the argument at first?

I am just creating the scenario which should at first delete the object if existing. Deletion I am doing in delete-object.feature.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the docs, the (single) `call` argument always has to be a JSON or array of JSONs (unless it is a call to a JS function): https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files

It is easy to shape, e.g. : `* def arg == { id: '#(id)' }`

Answer (score -1):

Just for the sake of reference, I'm posting a solution here.

```
* def id = response.content[0].id
  And eval if (size(response.content) == 1) { karate.call('delete/delete-object.feature') { id : '#(id)' } ; }
```

Inside delete-object.feature file, just use id to access that value. Keep in mind that there's a strange behavior in karate. If you pass in an object such as " { car: '#(carobject)'} ", you cannot access that object by calling "car" inside the feature file you pass this object in. You need to use the object name itself, not the attribute name. So, in this case, it would be "carobject". Hope that helps

Comment: this is wrong in 2 ways. it should be: `karate.call('delete/delete-object.feature', { id : id })` - and I suggest you read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

Comment: My bad, I mixed up with yours with  "call read("delete/delete-object.feature") { id : '#(id)' }" syntax